# How to completely uninstall java from RHEL?

Tags: rhel, symlink, rpm, java, uninstall

When I do `which java` I get the following output:

```
which java
/dir/java/bin/java
```

I have already uninstalled `java` `rpm` using the following

```
`rpm -qa | grep -i java`
rpm -e rpm-name
```

Still java is not installed and `which java` brings up  `/dir/java/bin/java`

Comment: That sounds like it was installed outside of `rpm` (or `yum`/`dnf`), so it's not in the database.

Comment: How to remove java in such a scenario?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently Java may have been installed outside of `rpm` package management.

In that case, you could just do a `mv /dir/java /dir/java.to-be-removed`, then verify that nothing essential gets broken by this.

If all seems OK, then remove any references to `/dir/java/bin` in system-wide `PATH` and `MANPATH` settings (check `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile`, and the files in `/etc/profile.d` directory if it exists) , delete any system-wide `JAVA_HOME` environment variable settings, and finally remove the `/dir/java.to-be-removed` directory altogether.

You might also check that `/usr/local/bin` directory doesn't contain any now-broken symbolic links pointing to the various tools within `/dir/java/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

try to find destination dirs from below commands.

`which java`

Or/and

`/usr/sbin/alternatives --display java`

One you find out delete those folder itself.

Since you already tried rpm way I am not adding. But be aware some other software which require java may not work after complete removal.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers; if you don't know whether a file belongs to an rpm or not, you can use:

```
rpm -qf /path/to/file
```

Which tells you to what rpm that file belongs.